# Вставить ссылку в csv-файл

Tags: php, csv, export

Коллеги, подскажите, пожалуйста. Как мне в csv-файл вставить гиперссылку на страницу в интернете - аналог `<a href="https://www.ligaportugal.pt/pt/liga/jogo/20192020/liganos/25/9">Match</a>`? Я делаю экспорт из БД в csv на php.

Comment: Какой ещё аналог? CSV - это текстовый файл, пишите в него свою ссылку как вам нужно.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы вместо урла был мой текст, но это была ссылка